# Is there a way to call base class function which is over-rided in its derived class that used private inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, using

I'm going through the inheritance concepts in C++ and tried such code:

```
class base{
    public:
    void display(int j)
    {
        cout<<j<< " base "<<endl;
    }
};

class derived:private base{
    public:
    using base::display;
    void display(int k)
    {
        cout<<k<< " derived "<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    derived obj;
    obj.display(10);
    //obj.base::display(46); --> cannot be used as base is privately inherited. Also conversion from derived to base cannot happen in this case.

    return 0;
}
```

In the above case, is there any way to invoke the base class `display` function from main by using `obj` in anyway?

If the base function is not over-rided in derived class, then by `using` (In case if the base functions are hidden with overloaded functions in derived), I could declare it in derived and invoke it with derived class `obj`. But in such cases where base function is over-rided  in derived with private inheritence, is there any way to invoke base function?

As I'm learning C++, I'm just curious to know if there is any way to do that thing (Irrespective of any practical use case).

Comment: `private` inheritance is special and probably least used. If you want to access a method from the base then you simply dont use `private` inheritance

Comment: @tobi303 As the OP pointed out, if you don’t override it, you can use private inheritance with a public `using`. This is useful if you want only *some* of the base class’s functionality visible. for example.

Comment: @tobi303, Thanks for the response. I know the ways to access base class functions. But I'm just curious to know in **this particular case** which I clearly mentioned. Because if the function is not overridden I can invoke the base class function with derived object even if they are hidden.

Comment: I believe the answer is “no; you just need to make the derived class use a different name or parameter list so it doesn’t override”, but I’m not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, because the function in the base class is private in the derived class, and that using declaration doesn't help here. But you can add a function to the derived class, with a different name, that calls the base function. No comment on the design issues that lead to this complexity.

Comment: Can you add information about why the `using` declaration doesn’t help? It’s just because it’s overriden, right?

Comment: @DanielH, exactly. If the function is overriden, then calling with object will invoke derived function rather than base function (if it's overloaded, with keyword `using` , it can be invoked directly as its something similar to **redeclare** the base class function explicitly in derived)

Comment: The reason that a `using` declaration doesn't help isn't that the base version is overridden; it's that the two functions have **the same signature**. If the base version wasn't virtual, a `using` directive still wouldn't make it callable from the derived class. The base version of the function would still have the same signature as the derived version, and there would still be no way to distinguish the two.

Answer (score -1):

Using virtual function concept it is possible to access the base class function inherited privately .
Use pointer object of base class and access the inherited member function by pointing the pointer object to the base class object and call display() function

Comment: How do you get a pointer to the base class when using private inheritance?

Comment: Because the inheritance was private; nobody outside knows that the derived class derives from the base class. You can do the conversion from *inside* the class, but not from outside.